# exchangeable $\sigma$-field generated by events that are invariant under permutation

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In Durrett's probability theory and examples, it says

> $$\Omega = \{ (\omega_1, \omega_2, \dots) : \omega_i \in S\}$$
> $$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{S} \times \dots $$
> $$X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$$
> Let $\mathcal{E}_n$ be the $\sigma$-field **generated by events that are invariant under permutations** that leave $n+1, n+2, \dots$ fixed and let $\mathcal{E} = \bigcap_n \mathcal{E}_n$ be the exchangeable $\sigma$-field.

Each event is unique (e.g. for tossing a coin twice, we'd get $\{HH\}, \{HT\}, \{TH\}, \{TT\}$) so how do we **measure** the invariance of events under permutation? What exactly do we mean by invariance?

For instance, $\{HT\}$ and $\{TH\}$ can be invariant to permutations if we have a random variable $X$ that counts the number of heads ($X(\{HT\}) = X(\{TH\}) = 1$). Then the $\sigma$-field generated by events that are invariant under permutation would be
$$\{ \{HT\}, \{TH\}, \{HT, TH \}, \{TT, HT, HH\}, \{TT, TH, HH \}, \{HH, TT, TH, HT\}, \emptyset \}?$$

Comment: For the two coin tosses example, the invariant $\sigma$ algebra should be the one generated by $\{ \{HH\}, \{HT, TH \}, \{TT \} \} $, since you cannot tell apart the outcomes $HT$ and $TH$.

Comment: @E-A when we say events are invariant under permutations, do we mean events are invariant under permutation **with respect to** some underlying random variable?

Comment: It should be the smallest sigma algebra that is generated by invariant random variables (i.e. random variables that don't depend on the orders of things in your outcomes). When $S$ is finite, I am pretty sure that implies that this is going to be the sigma algebra generated by sums of indicator random variables. I am not super confident though so I have not answered.

Comment: @E-A I see, that makes sense. Since the random variable $X$ I defined above does not depend on the order, as you said, I should generate a $\sigma$-algebra with $\{\{HH\}, \{HT, TH\}, \{TT\}\}$. But a random variable $Y$ that is $1$ when it sees two consecutive heads, then since it depends on the order of things, it would have a smaller, if not empty, sigma field generated by events that are invariant under permutation. So the above definition should say **with respect to some random variable**.